# How can I add a field to a MongoDB collection based off a field in the same collection?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

How can I add a field to a MongoDB collection based on a field in the same collection? For example, in this Collection:

```
{"_id" : "Apple", "colour": "green"}
{"_id" : "Apple", "colour": "red"}
```

I would like to add a third field in the collection "isGreen" so it would look like this:

```
{"_id" : "Apple", "colour" : "green", "isGreen" : "yes"}
{"_id" : "Apple", "colour" : "red", "isGreen" : "no"}
```

Is this possible with an aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$set` stage with `$cond` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "isGreen": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$colour",
              "green"
            ]
          },
          then: "yes",
          else: "no"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H40a1tAEw6b)

Comment: I'm getting "Unable to extract pipeline stages: the provided input is not an array of objects."

Comment: Hmmm, unsure what is this problem from? Can you share the query that you use?

Comment: I am using MongoDB compass "New Pipeline from plain text feature". I will edit the main post with the query I am trying to use

Comment: Ok, I know what is the problem, you just need to paste the array part in the text editor. Example: `[ { $set: { ... } } ]`

Comment: On which lines does the [{ and }] need to be added?

Comment: Suggested reading: [Import Pipeline from Text](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/import-pipeline-from-text/)